# How to access angular2+ service from external js file

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a string service in ts file in angular project and I want to access service, its methods and variables through external js file.

## service.ts

```
export class I18stringService {
    public i18: any;
    constructor() {
        this.i18 = {
            'name': 'Max'
        }
    }
}
```

## abc.js(external js) <=== added in angular.json

```
// getting  'Max' here
```